# Saving a click counter

Tags: javascript, html

I have a site where you have a picture and a counter below. When you click on the image, it plays a sound and the counter increments +1, but it doesn't save when i reload the page.

I would like my site have this behaviour:

- User A clicks on the picture 10 times
- User B opens the site and the counter is at 10, he clicks and now the counter starts 11
- User C opens the site ande the counter is at 11

and so on with the new users.

**My javascript functions :**

```
function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  counter();
}

function counter() {
  var n = localStorage.getItem('save');
  if (n === null) {
    n = 0;
  }
  n++;

  localStorage.setItem("save", n);
  document.getElementById('cpt').innerHTML = n;
}
```

**My HTML :**

```
<script src="ah.js"></script>

  <div id="img">
    <img src="ah!.png" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="ah.mp3" ></audio>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well you have to save it somewhere serverside.

Comment: What server-side language are you using? What are you going to store the number in?

Comment: you will have to permanetly synchronize the counter with your server, so you  will have to invoke a Ajax to your server, each time, someone clicks. Or maybe even better, as Maurizio Battaghini suggested a WebSocket. Depends on the click frequency.

Comment: Something like a DB ?

Comment: You should develop a system to save datas serverside / in a database and livereload the count. I suggest you to use firebase and websockets

Comment: It can be a DB, or simply a text file containing the click counter.

Comment: as per comments only way to allow multiple users to have a commonly associated counter is a server side solution. Also - for other implementations - note that local and session storage store all data as strings so will need to be parsed into a number before calculations or incrementing.

Comment: @MaurizioBattaghini Firebase and WebSockets to increment a counter? That seems like overkill to me.

Comment: Well i didn't saw the problem like that, i haven't any skills in server-side languages. Time to develop and improve them, so !

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez yes it's overengineerized but it's a good work to learn something usefull (i often adopt this practice to learn)

Comment: I think for this site, Firebase is really too much. This site is just one sigle page url: http://www.ah-27.fr

Comment: @Papaya yes, firebase and websockets are the "level up", just a suggestion to learn something useful and fun (if you start from scratch with server side technologies)

Comment: @MaurizioBattaghini Yes, I really start from scratch